# How to have more than one condition for data recall

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my MySQL database that looks like the following

```
banner
--------
 id  : bigint(20)
name : varchar(75)
type : set('news','event')
link : bigint(20)
when : int(10)
```

What I want to do is I want to be able to recall all the rows with the type of "news"
but I only want to recall all of the rows with the type of "event" where 'when > time()'
or basically any event that takes place in the future

RECAP:

- recall all NEWS items
- recall only EVENTS that happen in the future

I'm running the SQL query using PHP as the scripting language.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had tried something akin to what Lukasz Lysik suggested but was still getting past events.

i think the following solved it

```
SELECT * 
FROM `banner` 
WHERE IF(`type` = 'event', `when` > NOW(), 1) 
ORDER BY `when` DESC
```

Comment: im hoping im understanding this usage right

WHERE IF( *CONDITION* , *USE IF TRUE* , *USE IF FALSE* )

Comment: That has to be some of the least comprehensible notation imaginable.  The OR version above is far clearer.

Comment: im more concerned with proper functionality then clean code.  If it doesnt do what i need it to i couldnt care less how clean it is

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM banner 
WHERE type = "news" 
    OR (type = "event" AND when > NOW())
```

Comment: Would you send some data from the table?

Comment: If the condition '`when > NOW()`' is valid, then the query should work.  However, your `when` column is storing a 10-digit integer, but NOW() returns a DATETIME value.  I suspect that the trouble is that the comparison is not working as you expect - you should change 'when' to a date/time type (maybe DATETIME, maybe TIMESTAMP).

Comment: i have tried using when as a Timestamp but for whatever reason when i do that it is stored as a formated date instead of a raw timestamp.  I dont know if that is something with the MySQL build im using or what